# How to use Python Requests to make this POST request

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm trying to POST to the Adobe Sign API. Even if you're not familiar with the API, this should be a pretty straightforward question.

Sign's documentation says the POST I need to do looks like this:

```
POST /api/rest/v5/transientDocuments HTTP/1.1
Host: api.na1.echosign.com
Access-Token: MvyABjNotARealTokenHkYyi
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="File"; filename="MyPDF.pdf"

<PDF CONTENT>
```

Here is my current code, using Python Requests:

```
def createTransientDocument(your_file_base_url, file_name):
    headers = {'access-token': datafile.accessToken,
               'x-user-email': '<redacted for StackOverflow>',
               'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}

    files = {'file': (file_name, open(your_file_base_url + file_name, 'rb'))}

    r = requests.post(datafile.transient_documents_URL, files = files, headers=headers)

    return r
```

Unfortunately, this is not quite what the API is looking for. I get a response:

```
*{"code":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"The request provided is invalid"}*
```

Any tips on how to use the Requests library to POST my PDF file to this API?

Sorry for the n00b question, but I am learning the Requests library right now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's a nuance, but you need to name the file "File" with a capital F. Otherwise the API doesn't pick it up on the Adobe Sign side. Here is the correct (and working) API call.

```
def createTransientDocument(your_file_base_url, file_name):
    headers = {'access-token': datafile.accessToken,
               'x-user-email': '<email redacted>',
               'content-disposition':'form-data'}

    files = {'File': open(your_file_base_url+file_name, 'rb')}


    r = requests.post(datafile.transient_documents_URL, files=files, headers=headers)

    return r
```